# Undefined Index when variable is present

Tags: php, mysql

Code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['g'])) {
    if ($_REQUEST['g'] == "Set") {
        $g = strtolower($_REQUEST['g'])."_title";
    }else{
        $g = strtolower($_REQUEST['g']);
    }
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT LEFT($g, 1) FROM cards GROUP BY $g ORDER BY $g ASC");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { 
?> 
<a href="./index.php?route=<?php echo $var[0]."/".$var[1]."&g=".$_REQUEST['g']; ?>&sort=<?php echo substr($row[$g], 0, 1); ?>"><?php echo substr($row[$g], 0, 1); ?></a>&nbsp;     
<?php 
    } 
}
?>
```

Error Message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: set_title in E:\xampp\htdocs\zipdown\include\sort.php on line 11
```

What am i missing?

Comment: You are missing a sane database design, apparently. And security, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to escape the value of `$g` if it isn't known to be `Set`.

```
$g = mysql_real_escape_string($g);
```

Alias the column created by `LEFT()` as `$g`, enclosed in backticks:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT LEFT(`$g`, 1) AS `$g` FROM cards GROUP BY `$g` ORDER BY `$g` ASC");
//----------------------------------------^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise, the column name returned by your `mysql_fetch_array()` call is something like:

```
$row['LEFT(set_title,1)']
```

#### Note on security:

Given that your database must have a finite set of column names, it is advisable to use a whitelist against which you check the value of `$g`:

```
// Assuming your columns are named title, author, etc...
if (in_array($g, array('title','author','set_title','publisher','whatever'))) {
   // do the rest of your work
}
else {
   // Invalid value to $_REQUEST['g']
}
```

Comment: that would be not the great idea in terms of security

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I had not noticed the use of `$g` when not `Set`.  Changed to be escaped and quoted above...

Comment: in fact your changes added nothing to security

Comment: by the way, mysql_real_escape_string() does not escape backticks. Just to let you know.

Comment: @rackemup420 See addition above column whitelisting for $g

Answer (score 0):

You should give an alias name for `LEFT($g, 1)`, or the key name in result is just lkie `LEFT(set_title, 1)` if `$g` is `set_title`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$g` has the value of `set_title` and your `$row` does not have an element at that index.
To be more clear, `$row['set_title']` does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

If you ask for `$row['set_title']` but there is no such key `set_title` available in `$row`, PHP will raise a notice to let you know that it couldn't find anything. It will return a null value.

This is a **notice**, not an error. Generally speaking, notices only show up when PHP is set up for development; for production sites, notices are usually turned off.

Check out the documentation here if you want to silence notices:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: yeah this is a development server on a local pc.

Comment: What is the reason for turning off notices on the production server?

Comment: Notices are just warnings, not errors, so the idea is you might not want PHP notices (with file names, line numbers, etc.) on your production site. It might be OK on a dev site when you want help and all the debugging information available.